# Everything redirecting to index.php but still direct access to PDF's

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, redirect

I have a PHP-Project, where I am redirecting every URL to `index.php`.
But the files in uploads folder (.png, .pdf, etc.) can be accessed directly.
Is there a way to prevent this and also redirect URLs like `https://example.com/uploads/asdf.pdf` to `index.php`.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Made some changes on the `.htaccess` file, but did not help.

Comment: Do you know what your line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` actually does? Now consider that those PDF files are actual files in your file system, obviously. So what will be the effect of that line?

Comment: I get it, but it has to load the JS and CSS files and when I delete the line of code, it is not loading those files. So I need something, which loads the css and js files, but not pdf's.

Comment: Usually one does not allow direct access to files _at all_ . Instead all requests are routed through a script, also those requesting physical files like your documents. That allows to implement flexible access controls. And keeps things like actual storage path away from the client where it does not belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
> ```

To rewrite all requests that do not map to physical files OR that map to `.pdf` files in the `/uploads` directory to `index.php` then you can basically just add an additional `OR`'d condition to the above rule.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/[^/]+\.pdf$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

So, the above states that any request of the form `/uploads/<file>.pdf` (regardless of whether that `.pdf` file exists or not) *OR* that does not map to a physical is rewritten to `index.php`.

If you wish to rewrite *everything* in the `/uploads` directory through `index.php` then simply change the regex from `^/uploads/[^/]+\.pdf$` to `^/uploads/`.

I also simplified (and made more efficient) the regex in the `RewriteRule` directive (since you don't need to match and capture everything) and the `QSA` flag was redundant here.

---

**UPDATE:**

> How is it possible with files, which are in a subfolder of the uploads folder?

You can tweak the regex in the preceding condition (`RewriteCond` directive). For example...

- A specific subfolder of the uploads folder:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/subfolder/[^/]+\.pdf$ [OR]
  :
  ```
- Any subfolder of the uploads folder:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/[^/]+/[^/]+\.pdf$ [OR]
  :
  ```
- Any `.pdf` file under the `/uploads` folder (including any subfolder):

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.+\.pdf$ [OR]
  :
  ```

See the following question for details on regular expressions (regex):
[Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Yes it works for the files in the uploads folder! Thanks a lot. How is it possible with files, which are in a subfolder of the uploads folder?

Comment: @ibo_dc I've updated my answer with some examples.